# The property 'Content' is set more than once Button WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I've read some other answers, but I can't quite fathom out why mine is still throwing this error:

```
<Grid Grid.Column="2" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Grid.Column="3" Width="24" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding LocalisedResource[delete_48.png].Image}" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding ShowConfigCommand}" Grid.Column="0" Width="24" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding LocalisedResource[software_24.png].Image}" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
```

People aren't getting this error, so I will post the rest of the code:

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Background>
            <SolidColorBrush Color="Black" />
        </Grid.Background>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="50" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>


        <TextBlock Text="{Binding LocalisedText[app.title]}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Style="{DynamicResource MainWindowTitleTextStyle}" />

        <Grid Grid.Column="2" Width="100" Height="30" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Button Command="{Binding }" Grid.Column="3" Width="24" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding LocalisedResource[delete_48.png].Image}" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
            <Button Command="{Binding }" Grid.Column="0" Width="24" Height="24" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Button.Template>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding LocalisedResource[software_24.png].Image}" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
                        </StackPanel>

                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Button.Template>
            </Button>
        </Grid>

        <!-- Popup Box -->
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Grid.Row="2" Grid.RowSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />

        <!-- Connected View Goes Here -->
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" />

        <!-- Demo View Goes Here -->
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" />

        <!-- Configuration -->
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding }" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="50" />
    </Grid>
```

Comment: I see no such error with your posted code.

Comment: I can't find any error too. This code works fine in my case...

Comment: what about where you use this button in your code?

Comment: I've added more information :)

Comment: The error doesn't show with your new code in my environment I'm afraid.

Comment: Could it be due to MVVM and Visual Studio 2012 not processing it correctly? It doesn't stop the build or run process, I was just wondering whether it could be surpressed?

Comment: I can't try your code sorry. I had this error when the control template had defined a content and then I tried to use a button with content on my page: <button>text</button>

Comment: copy-paste and i have no error vs2010, this is inside a usercontrol ?

Comment: Its in a resource dictionary which has a datatemplate, because of using the MVVM